# Comparing soccer teams name

Tags: nlp

Which is the best way to compare soccer teams from different sites? For example, one soccer team in a site is named `Academica Clinceni` and in another `FC Clinceni` and in  another one is `Acs Fc Academica Clinceni`.
Moreover, for a team can exist also the female version of the team (eg. `Acs Fc Academica Clinceni (W)` or `Acs Fc Academica Clinceni (F)`). Which is the best approach to distinguish these teams? For the first problem I used the *Fuzzy String Matching*, in your opinion is it right?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know why your question was voted down! Fuzzy matching is such a common challenge. The best approach I’ve seen is this one: https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-matching-at-scale-84f2bfd0c536 It gives similar results to something like Levenshtein distance but it’s much faster. If you augment the matching approach with hand-coded regex features to spot e.g. female versus male teams, you should be able to match teams pretty well.